# How to get all the Products from Amazon Seller Account into Private App?

Tags: saas, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am developing a private application in ReactJs and NestJs for Amazon Seller Central using Amazon SP-API. I have completed the authorization step. Now I want to get all the products from the Amazon Seller Account and store them in a local database. But I can't find any Amazon SP-API endpoint which returns all the products from the Amazon seller account.

Every Api I have checked, they required some kind on information which we don't have prior of the API request like SkU or ASIN. I need API which get all the products from amazon seller account or any other solution to make it possible.

Comment: Maybe you want one of these inveontory reports? https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/report-type-values-inventory